# How to update rails 2.3.10 to 3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

Currently I am using rails 2.3.10, I want to update my rails version to version 3.
What's the command to update rails?

Comment: @kchau and @sam already covered it, but just to be sure, the upgrade is more involved than just running a rake task. Rails3 addresses models very differently. Depending on which gems you're using, functionality of your existing code may completely break.

Answer (score 6):

So, the basic command would be:

```
gem update rails
```

But, upgrading from 2.3.x to 3.x isn't a trivial task... you should really [read](http://www.railsdispatch.com/posts/upgrading-a-rails-2-app-to-rails-3) up a [little](http://www.railsinside.com/screencasts/373-rails-3-upgrade-screencast.html) [more](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1) on it before you do so.

Answer (score 4):

Ryan Bates shows you how to do it [here](http://railscasts.com/episodes/225-upgrading-to-rails-3-part-1). The Rails version you are using are completely different so you will have to upgrade Rails and then use this [plugin](https://github.com/rails/rails_upgrade/blob/master/README) to help upgrade your application unless you already know everything.